After running apt upgrade Intel MIPI camera is now blank
I'm using a Dell Latitude 7440 and Ubuntu 22.04. I ran sudo apt upgrade this morning and now my camera is broken. It is detected, but the camera screen is black. There is no video shown Google Meet or if I use https://webcamtests.com/ it says the video track is paused.
I had issues with the camera weeks ago where it wouldn't even detect the camera, but I fixed it then.
How can I revert back to whatever packages I had in use for the camera?
Here is the apt log.
2024-12-10 08:44:18 upgrade gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 2.46.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 2.46.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 
2024-12-10 08:44:19 upgrade gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 2.46.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 2.46.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 
2024-12-10 08:44:19 upgrade libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 2.46.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 2.46.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 
2024-12-10 08:44:19 upgrade libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 2.46.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 2.46.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 
2024-12-10 08:44:22 upgrade libexpat1:amd64 2.4.7-1ubuntu0.4 2.4.7-1ubuntu0.5 
2024-12-11 08:41:02 upgrade intel-microcode:amd64 3.20240910.0ubuntu0.22.04.1 3.20241112.0ubuntu0.22.04.1 
2024-12-17 08:15:16 upgrade libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.19 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.20 
2024-12-17 08:15:19 upgrade curl:amd64 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.19 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.20 
2024-12-17 08:15:19 upgrade libcurl4:amd64 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.19 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.20 
2024-12-17 08:15:22 upgrade linux-tools-common:all 5.15.0-126.136 5.15.0-127.137 
2024-12-27 09:34:53 upgrade gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.1 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.3 
2024-12-27 09:34:54 upgrade libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.1 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.3 
2024-12-27 09:34:57 upgrade gstreamer1.0-gtk3:amd64 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.1 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.3 
2024-12-27 09:35:00 upgrade gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps:amd64 1.20.1-1ubuntu0.2 1.20.1-1ubuntu0.4 
2024-12-27 09:35:04 upgrade gstreamer1.0-tools:amd64 1.20.3-0ubuntu1 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.1 
2024-12-27 09:35:07 upgrade libgstreamer1.0-0:amd64 1.20.3-0ubuntu1 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.1 
2024-12-27 09:35:10 upgrade gstreamer1.0-gl:amd64 1.20.1-1ubuntu0.2 1.20.1-1ubuntu0.4 
2024-12-27 09:35:14 upgrade gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64 1.20.1-1ubuntu0.2 1.20.1-1ubuntu0.4 
2024-12-27 09:35:17 upgrade gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64 1.20.1-1ubuntu0.2 1.20.1-1ubuntu0.4 
2024-12-27 09:35:20 upgrade gstreamer1.0-x:amd64 1.20.1-1ubuntu0.2 1.20.1-1ubuntu0.4 
2024-12-27 09:35:23 upgrade libgstreamer-gl1.0-0:amd64 1.20.1-1ubuntu0.2 1.20.1-1ubuntu0.4 
2024-12-27 09:35:26 upgrade libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64 1.20.1-1ubuntu0.2 1.20.1-1ubuntu0.4 
2024-12-27 09:35:29 upgrade gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.1 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.3 
2024-12-27 09:35:32 upgrade gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0:amd64 1.20.3-0ubuntu1 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.1 
2024-12-27 09:35:35 upgrade gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0:amd64 1.20.1-1ubuntu0.2 1.20.1-1ubuntu0.4 
2024-12-27 12:55:39 upgrade libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.3 
2024-12-27 12:55:39 upgrade libglx-mesa0:amd64 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.3 
2024-12-27 12:55:39 upgrade libegl-mesa0:amd64 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.3 
2024-12-27 12:55:39 upgrade libglapi-mesa:amd64 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.3 
2024-12-27 12:55:40 upgrade libgbm1:amd64 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.3 
2024-12-27 12:55:40 upgrade brave-browser:amd64 1.73.91 1.73.104 
2024-12-27 12:55:45 upgrade dmidecode:amd64 3.3-3ubuntu0.1 3.3-3ubuntu0.2 
2024-12-27 12:55:45 upgrade alsa-ucm-conf:all 1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.11 1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.12 
2024-12-27 12:55:45 upgrade code:amd64 1.95.3-1731513102 1.96.2-1734607745 
2024-12-27 12:55:54 upgrade libpackagekit-glib2-18:amd64 1.2.5-2ubuntu2 1.2.5-2ubuntu3 
2024-12-27 12:55:54 upgrade gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0:amd64 1.2.5-2ubuntu2 1.2.5-2ubuntu3 
2024-12-27 12:55:54 upgrade libcamhal0:amd64 0~git202410220058.74ffeab~ubuntu22.04.2 0~git202412180530.b6f6eeb~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:54 upgrade libcamhal-common:all 0~git202410220058.74ffeab~ubuntu22.04.2 0~git202412180530.b6f6eeb~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:54 upgrade gstreamer1.0-icamera:amd64 0~git202410220058.4877b66~ubuntu22.04.3 0~git202411290835.ee85264~ubuntu22.04.2 
2024-12-27 12:55:54 upgrade libgsticamerainterface-1.0-1:amd64 0~git202410220058.4877b66~ubuntu22.04.3 0~git202411290835.ee85264~ubuntu22.04.2 
2024-12-27 12:55:55 upgrade packagekit-tools:amd64 1.2.5-2ubuntu2 1.2.5-2ubuntu3 
2024-12-27 12:55:55 upgrade gstreamer1.0-packagekit:amd64 1.2.5-2ubuntu2 1.2.5-2ubuntu3 
2024-12-27 12:55:55 upgrade packagekit:amd64 1.2.5-2ubuntu2 1.2.5-2ubuntu3 
2024-12-27 12:55:55 upgrade libia-log-ipu6ep0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:55 upgrade libbroxton-ia-pal-ipu6ep0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:55 upgrade libia-log-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:55 upgrade libbroxton-ia-pal-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:55 upgrade libgcss-ipu6ep0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:55 upgrade libgcss-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:55 upgrade libia-aiqb-parser-ipu6ep0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:55 upgrade libia-coordinate-ipu6ep0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:55 upgrade libia-exc-ipu6ep0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:55 upgrade libia-mkn-ipu6ep0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:55 upgrade libia-nvm-ipu6ep0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:55 upgrade libia-aiq-ipu6ep0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:55 upgrade libia-aiqb-parser-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:56 upgrade libia-coordinate-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:56 upgrade libia-exc-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:56 upgrade libia-mkn-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:56 upgrade libia-nvm-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:56 upgrade libia-aiq-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:56 upgrade libia-bcomp-ipu6ep0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:56 upgrade libia-bcomp-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:56 upgrade libia-ccat-ipu6ep0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:56 upgrade libia-cmc-parser-ipu6ep0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:56 upgrade libia-dvs-ipu6ep0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:56 upgrade libia-emd-decoder-ipu6ep0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:56 upgrade libia-isp-bxt-ipu6ep0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:57 upgrade libia-lard-ipu6ep0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:57 upgrade libia-ltm-ipu6ep0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:57 upgrade libia-cca-ipu6ep0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:57 upgrade libia-ccat-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:57 upgrade libia-cmc-parser-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:57 upgrade libia-dvs-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:57 upgrade libia-emd-decoder-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:57 upgrade libia-isp-bxt-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:57 upgrade libia-lard-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:57 upgrade libia-ltm-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:57 upgrade libia-cca-ipu6epmtl0:amd64 0~git202410220058.e00b29f-1~ubuntu22.04.1 0~git202411270842.3c1cdd3-1~ubuntu22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:57 upgrade libxatracker2:amd64 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.3 
2024-12-27 12:55:59 upgrade linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.8.0-49.49~22.04.1 6.8.0-50.51~22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:55:59 upgrade linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.8.0-49.49~22.04.1 6.8.0-50.51~22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:56:02 upgrade linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.8.0-49.49~22.04.1 6.8.0-50.51~22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:56:02 upgrade linux-tools-common:all 5.15.0-127.137 5.15.0-130.140 
2024-12-27 12:56:02 upgrade linux-libc-dev:amd64 5.15.0-128.138 5.15.0-130.140 
2024-12-27 12:56:02 upgrade linux-modules-ipu6-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.8.0-49.49~22.04.1 6.8.0-50.51~22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:56:02 upgrade linux-oem-22.04:amd64 6.8.0-49.49~22.04.1 6.8.0-50.51~22.04.1 
2024-12-27 12:56:03 upgrade mesa-va-drivers:amd64 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.3 
2024-12-27 12:56:03 upgrade mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.3 
2024-12-27 12:56:03 upgrade mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.3 
2024-12-27 12:56:03 upgrade python3-paramiko:all 2.9.3-0ubuntu1.2 2.9.3-0ubuntu1.3 
2024-12-27 12:56:03 upgrade snapd:amd64 2.65.3+22.04 2.66.1+22.04

